# Question sort: change active to activity?

Tags: bug, status-completed, sort

I noticed the sort `newest` for `/questions`, `/questions/tagged/{tags}` and `/questions/unanswered` was changed to `creation` recently, making it more consistent with other methods. Could the sort `active` for `/questions` and `/questions/tagged/{tags}` be changed to `activity` for the same reason?

Comment: did you catch the twitter update last night? ;-)

Comment: Yep, I saw that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This went out tonight.